# How to wait for all tasks to finish before terminating the event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

What's the standard way in Python to ensure that all concurrent tasks are completed before the event loop ends? Here's a simplified example:

```
import asyncio

async def foo(delay):
    print("Start foo.") # Eg: Send message
    asyncio.create_task(bar(delay))
    print("End foo.")

async def bar(delay):
    print("Start bar.")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print("End bar.") # Eg: Delete message after delay

def main():
    asyncio.run(foo(2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Current output:

```
Start foo. # Eg: Send message
End foo.
Start bar.
```

Desired output:

```
Start foo. # Eg: Send message
End foo.
Start bar.
End bar. # Eg: Delete message after delay
```

I've tried to run all outstanding tasks after `loop.run_until_complete()`, but that doesn't work since the loop will have been terminated by then. I've also tried modifying the main function to the following:

```
async def main():
    await foo(2)

    tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
    if len(tasks) > 0:
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is correct, but it never terminates since the coroutine `main()` is one of the tasks. The setup above is also how `discord.py` sends a message and deletes it after a period of time, except that it uses `loop.run_forever()` instead, so does not encounter the problem.

Comment: Try: `task = [asyncio.create_task(bar(delay))]` and then `await asyncio.gather(*task, return_exceptions=False)` in your foo function.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't interact with the loop directly these days. Use ``asyncio.run`` instead of getting and starting the loop manually.

Comment: @user56700 I tried it, but it locks `foo` until bar completes. `bar` has to be run concurrently. An example is a bot sending a message with an expiration. The function for sending the message should run as quickly as possible and return (calling function only wants to wait till message is sent, not until message expires).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, I edited the post with the improved code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard way to wait for all tasks in `asyncio` (and similar frameworks), and in fact one should not try to. Speaking in terms of threads, a `Task` expresses *both* [regular and daemon activities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon). Waiting for all tasks indiscriminately may cause an application to stall indefinitely.

A task that is created but never `await`ed is de-facto a background/daemon task. In contrast, if a task should not be treated as background/daemon then it is the callers responsibility to ensure it is `await`ed.

---

The simplest solution is for every coroutine to `await` and/or cancel all tasks it spawns.

```py
async def foo(delay):
    print("Start foo.")
    task = asyncio.create_task(bar(delay))
    print("End foo.")
    await task  # foo is done here, it ensures the other task finishes as well
```

Since the entire point of `async`/tasks is to have cheap task switching, this is a cheap operation. It should also not affect any well-designed applications:

- If the purpose of a function is to produce a value, any child tasks should be part of producing that value.
- If the purpose of a function is some side-effect, any child tasks should be parts of that side-effect.

For more complex situations, it can be worthwhile to *return* any outstanding tasks.

```
async def foo(delay):
    print("Start foo.")
    task = asyncio.create_task(bar(delay))
    print("End foo.")
    return task  # allow the caller to wait for our child tasks
```

This requires the caller to explicitly handle outstanding tasks, but gives prompt replies and the most control. The top-level task is then responsible for handling any orphan tasks.

For `async` programming in general, the [structured programming paradigm](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/) encodes the idea of "handling outstanding tasks" in a managing object. In Python, this pattern has been encoded by [the `trio` library](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as so-called `Nursery` objects.

```py
import trio

async def foo(delay, nursery):
    print("Start foo.")
    # spawning a task via a nursery means *someone* awaits it
    nursery.start_soon(bar, delay)
    print("End foo.")

async def bar(delay):
    print("Start bar.")
    await trio.sleep(delay)
    print("End bar.")

async def main():
    # a task may spawn a nursery and pass it to child tasks
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        await foo(2, nursery)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

While this pattern has been suggested for [`asyncio` as `TaskGroups`, so far it has been deferred](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/6694).
Various ports of the pattern for `asyncio` are available via third-party libraries, however.